# Every Other 2 Items in Array

Tags: ruby

I need a ruby formula to create an array of integers. The array must be every other 2 numbers as follows.

```
[2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19...]
```

I have read a lot about how I can do every other number or multiples, but I am not sure of the best way to achieve what I need.

Comment: the array stops or you need an infinite enumerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach that works on any array.

```
def every_other_two arr
  arr.select.with_index do |_, idx|
    idx % 4 > 1
  end
end

every_other_two((0...20).to_a) # => [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19]

# it works on any array
every_other_two %w{one two three four five six} # => ["three", "four"]
```

Comment: why do you need to put a blank (_,idx) ? It works fine with :

def every_other_two arr
  arr.select.with_index do |idx|
    idx % 4 > 1
  end
end

Good tricky solution though. +1 :)

Comment: @K.M.RakibulIslam: and for the future, use services like http://pastie.org. It's impossible to post readable code in a comment.

Comment: ohh, got it :) for the 2nd array we need the _ :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
array = []
#Change 100000 to whatever is your upper limit
100000.times do |i|
  array << i if i%4 > 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for any start number to any end limit

```
i = 3
j = 19
x =[]
(i...j).each do |y|
  x << y if (y-i)%4<2
end
puts x
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

For fun, using lazy enumerables (requires Ruby 2.0 or gem enumerable-lazy):

```
(2..Float::INFINITY).step(4).lazy.map(&:to_i).flat_map { |x| [x, x+1] }.first(8)
#=> => [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution that works with infinite streams:

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |y| 
  (2...1/0.0).each_slice(4) do |slice| 
    slice[0 .. 1].each { |n| y.yield(n) }
  end
end

enum.first(10) #=> [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19]

enum.each do |n|
  puts n
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Single Liner:

```
(0..20).to_a.reduce([0,[]]){|(count,arr),ele| arr << ele if count%4 > 1;
                                                           [count+1,arr] }.last
```

Explanation:

Starts the reduce look with 0,[] in count,arr vars

Add current element to array if condition satisfied. Block returns increment and arr for the next iteration.

I agree though that it is not so much of a single liner though and a bit complex looking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more general version of Sergio's fine answer

```
module Enumerable
  def every_other(slice=1)
    mod = slice*2
    res = select.with_index { |_, i| i % mod >= slice }
    block_given? ? res.map{|x| yield(x)} : res
  end
end

irb> (0...20).every_other
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
irb> (0...20).every_other(2)
=> [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19]
irb> (0...20).every_other(3)
=> [3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]
irb> (0...20).every_other(5) {|v| v*10 }
=> [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190]
```